# How to access array class in kotlin from functions

Tags: kotlin

```
var atmarray = arrayListOf<ATM>()
class ATM(
    val AccountName:String="",
    val Pin:Int=0,
    val IntialDeposit:Double=0.0
)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
mainmenu()
}

fun mainmenu(){
println("WELCOME TO BANK AL BILAL ATM MACHINE")
println("1- Add Account\n2- Login Account\n3-Exit")
var input1= readLine()!!.toInt()
when(input1){
    1->add()
    2->login()
    3-> Exit()
}
}

fun add(){
println("Enter Your Name")
val Name= readLine()!!.toString()
println("Enter Your 4-Digit Account Pin")
var Pin= readLine()!!.toInt()
println("Confirm Your 4-Digit Account Pin")
var Pin1= readLine()!!.toInt()
if (Pin!=Pin1){
    println("Sorry Your Pin didn't Match, Try Again")
    add()
}
else{
    println("Pin Verified Successfully")
}
println("Enter the Amount to Deposit")
var FirstDeposit= readLine()!!.toDouble()
atmarray.add(ATM(Name,Pin,FirstDeposit ))
mainmenu()
}

fun login(){
println("Enter your Account Name")
var AcName=readLine()!!.toString()
println("Enter your 4-digit Account Pin")
var AcPin= readLine()!!.toInt()
// Need help here how to verify login by accessing atmarray class
}

fun Exit(){
println("GOOD BYE VALUEABLE CUSTOMER")
mainmenu()
}
```

Note: I am trying to create a login section for user but I am having problem in accessing the atmarray class above. I want to know how can I access account name and pin available in atmarray class by if else in login section.

Comment: That's a fair amount of code.  Please isolate the code that is generating random input and then calculates the results and post the inputs obtained vs what you expect.  I think that will help others see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
atmarray.find { account -> account.AccountName == AcName }?.let { selectedAccount ->
   if (selectedAccount.Pin == AcPin) {
       //login success
   }
}
```